# How to use data in between other data in excel using python pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel sheet with metrics that I need but also some of it is garbage data. The data I need starts after row 65 and is a growing list so I can't specify when to stop looking. There are a few empty rows just after the data I need so I'm trying to get it to locate that empty row so it only uses that data. I also want it to filter that list of anything that contains cc-mrkt or a blank in column B.

I've tried the code below but I get IndexError: list index out of range when trying to run the First_Blank line. I'm quite new to programming so any help that can be provided will be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd

def MetricCleanup():

    df1 = pd.read_csv('./Metric Data/2020-03-30.csv', skiprows = 65)
    First_Blank = df1[df1.isnull().all(axis=1) == True].index.tolist()[0]
    Data = df1.loc[0:First_Blank]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the python module openpyxl it makes it easier to read, edit and search for data in excelsheats.
To get this module inside of python interpreter or the terminal by you python ide.(I use Pycharm) write:

with python3 and up:

```
pip3 install openpyxl
```

with python2:

```
pip install openpyxl
```

Then import it:

```
import openpyxl as xl
```

saying import as xl makes it easier so you don't always have to write openpyxl when you want to acces it instead you just write xl.
Then download the excel spreadsheet and move it into the folder Pycharmprojects on your computer. It has to be in the same project folder as this python file. If you don't use Pycharm as an ide just ask me and ill help you with that.

```
def MetricCleanup(filename):
    def process_workbook(filename):
    wb = xl.load_workbook(filename)
    sheet = wb['Sheet1']

for row in range(row where data starts, sheet.max_row + 1):
    cell = sheet.cell(row, (column with data)) 
    (Here goes the code to sort out the trash :) )

   
wb.save(filename)
```

This is just so python knows which file to open:

process_workbook('(here you put excel file name with .xlxs at the end)')

In case you don't want to use openpyxl, but instead you want to use pandas, you should download it as a .xlsx file and the code to read the file would now be:

```
import pandas as pd

def MetricCleanup():

     df1 = pd.read_excel('./Metric Data/2020-03-30.xlsx', skiprows = 65)
     First_Blank = df1[df1.isnull().all(axis=1) == True].index.tolist()[0]
     Data = df1.loc[0:First_Blank]
```

Comment: If you have any questions just ask, im free almost always unless i'm at school :)

Comment: Hi Remi, it looks like openpyxl doesn't support csv format. Do you know if there is a way to do it with pandas?

Comment: This is just a question to help me understand a bit more what the problem could be: The csv file is in the same directory or folder as your python file right? So, if you double click on the csv file, can you open the excel file or does it just open a  text file?

Comment: If it opens as a text file, you might have to just download it again but as a .xlxs file. I edited my answer to add at the end how you would do it in pandas. (With an xlsx file)

Comment: I tried the second one showed before and I got an error - IndexError: list index out of range.

Comment: The csv opens in excel but it's a csv format so openpyxl doesn't support it

Comment: Is what you showed the whole code or is there more. If there is more could you send that, as I can't find out where the IndexError is coming from without the code

Comment: That's the whole code so far. I was going to integrate this into another script I have so it will be fully automated

Comment: For me when I write all this it works fine, the only difference between ours is that by df1 = pd.read_csv('./Metric Data/2020-03-30.csv', skiprows = 65) i have: df1 = pd.read_csv('./Metric Data/2020-03-30 - Sheet1.csv', skiprows = 65)

Comment: so at the end of the filename id did: filename - Sheet1.csv

Comment: Looks like the error was resolved when I specified columns to use.
df1 = pd.read_csv('./Metric Data/2020-03-30.csv', skiprows = 65, usecols[1,2])

Comment: Well that's good, although I don't know where the error could have come from, as by me, with the same exact code, it work fine without an error.

Comment: I'm not sure, it might have to do with the how the data is placed throughout the CSV that gets downloaded. Not all data in the sheet is in the same exact columns so maybe by specifying it is able to understand the range better?

Comment: Yeah, that does make sense